# LazyInitializationException when accessing LAZY collection on User

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a User class containing a collection of lazy loaded objects.

```
class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Getter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private List<Wallet> wallets= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now I also have a Transaction class which contains a reference to the User's wallet.

```
class Transaction {
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "senderWallet", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Wallet senderWallet;
}
```

Now I created a service which is supposed to fetch the transactions for a given user:

```
@Transactional
public List<Transaction> getTransactionsForUser(User user) {
    List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets();
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Wallet wallet : wallets) {
        transactions.addAll(transactionRepository.findBySenderWallet(wallet));
    }

    return transactions;
}
```

In the controller, I'm fetching the current logged in user like this:

```
User user = ((UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();
```

Afterwards, I make a call to the service:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = transactionService.getTransactionsForUser(user);
```

And this throws a LazyInitializationException. What's the workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I think that your `@OneToMany` should have the `mappedBy` defined:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
@Getter
@Column(nullable = false)
private List<Wallet> wallets= new ArrayList<>();
```

**2)** You are passing an entity `User` which has been fetched in a different transactional context which seems to be closed now.

In the service method you should perform a **merge** of that entity before proceding. Srping Data Jpa `save` method has merging implemented so calling that is sufficient:

```
@Transactional
public List<Transaction> getTransactionsForUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);  // Add this <---

    List<Wallet> wallets = user.getWallets();
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Wallet wallet : wallets) {
        transactions.addAll(transactionRepository.findBySenderWallet(wallet));
    }

    return transactions;
}
```

Comment: What's the reason behind 1? The user is the owner of the relationship.
2) That's what I've guessed, but it seems counterintuitive to do this every single time. Is there a different way to do what I'm trying to achieve? (in terms of design/architecture - maybe add a new method in the service that will fetch the logged in user in the service instead of fetching it in the controller)

Comment: The reason for 1 is that you have defined a `bidirectional` mapping but have not declared an `owning` entity. As a result your schema will have both a join table and a foreign key which is improper.

Comment: On top of that you use JoinColumn or JoinTable on OneToMany. Not Column as such does not exist on the owned entity.